# Detecting late responses

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I'm using Netty 3.3.1.

I wish to (1) abort sending a late response on server-side and (2) reject the late responses that came from the server on client-side.

My workflow is as follows. I send a request from the client and I expect the server to respond within 30 secs. If it doesn't, I assume something went wrong and I send the request all over again.
Now I'm worried that the client will receive the old response whilst expecting the new response. I want to detect that (mainly on client-side, but it would be cool, if the server decided not to send the response after 30 secs).

Can I use Netty's IdleStateHandler/WriteTimeoutHandler/ReadTimeoutHandler for that? Note that I don't disconnect the channel, but re-use it for future requests/responses and that the timer mustn't be reset on server, when the client re-sends the request via the same channel.

My second idea was to timestamp requests and responses.

OTOH, am I complicating things? Can late responses even happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way to handle this would be to have some kind of "id" which can be used to see if its an "old" response or not.